# Node JS get values from multiple promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

Basically what I wanted to do is wait and get the first two functions results and pass that value to 3rd function. Therefore with the Node Q module I tried the below code.

```
getAddressDetail("", 51.528308, -0.3817812).then(function (pickupLoc) {
    return pickupLoc.location;
}).then(function (pickupLocation) {
    var drop = getAddressDetail(, 51.528308, -0.3817812);
    return [pickupLocation,drop.location];
})
.then(function (pickupLocation, dropLocation) {
    console.log("#####" + pickupLocation +"$$$" + dropLocation)
})
.done();
```

**EDIT**

```
function getAddressDetail(location = "", lat, long) {

  var deferred = Q.defer();

  var getLocation = "";
  if (location == '' || location == 'undefined') {

    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={APIKEY}&latlng=' + lat + ',' + long + '&sensor=false';

    request({
      url: url,
      json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        getLocation = body.results[0].formatted_address;
        deferred.resolve({
          'location': getLocation
        });
        //console.log("*******" +  getLocation);
      }

    })
  } else {
    getLocation = location;
    deferred.resolve({
      'location': getLocation
    });
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

However this code doesn't return value which defined in the 2nd then code "dropLocation", it return as undefined. Do you see any issues in here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `getAddressDetail` return a promise?

Comment: yep see the edit.

Comment: You are not waiting for the 2nd `getAddressDetail` to finish, that is why you have the issue with `dropLocation` begin `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of dodgy things happening in your code.

1. `return [pickupLocation,drop.location]` wil result in 1 parameter (an array) in the next handler, so instead of `.then(function (pickupLocation, dropLocation) {})` you should use `.then(function (results) {})`
2. `var drop = getAddressDetail(, 51.528308, -0.3817812);`looks like it isn't a promise because you immediately get the location from the result. (`return [pickupLocation,drop.location];`) So why then not fetch this value in the next handler?
3. If getAddressDetail() DOES return a promise, just compose an array of promises and use the `.spread()` operation as the result of the first promise is not required in the second promise.

An example;

```
var promiseArray = [];

promiseArray.push(getAddressDetail("", 51.528308, -0.3817812));
promiseArray.push(getAddressDetail("", 51.528308, -0.3817812));

Q.spread(promiseArray, function(pickupLocation, drop){
  // first parameter (pickupLocation) = result of first promise
  // second parameter (drop) = result of second promise
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, this what I'm expecting. I'm actually new bie to node. May I know incase if the first promise fails, will Q.spread() code block will execute ?

Comment: The rejection handler will get called at the first sign of failure. That is, whichever of the received promises fails first gets handled by the rejection handler.